# Android: How to create an exact repeating alarm?

Tags: java, android, notifications, alarmmanager

I've basically finished my app, except for notifications. Ive gotten notifications to work fine and dandy, EXCEPT for letting them be exact AND repeating. This singular part has taken me two days of experimentation to try to fix but to no avail.

There are two things that I would like to do but am lost on how;

1. As stated above, getting an exact repeating alarm to function as intended.
2. Getting it to continue as intended after a reboot.

(If using broadcast receivers or similar please specify what code goes to which file. I've hit a wall a few times following the instructions on similar posts because of this issue.)

Thank you in advance. (Below is my current code)

---

**In MainActivity.class** (scheduleNotification() is called from a MaterialTimePicker)

```java
public void scheduleNotification(int hour, int minute) {
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiverNotification.class);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

        if (calendar.before(Calendar.getInstance())) {
            calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        }
        triggerTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, 24*3600*1000, pendingIntent);

        
        Log.v("Alarm", "Alarm set for " + hour + ":" + minute);
        logTimeUntilNotification();
    }
```

---

**In AlarmReceiverNotification.class**

```java
public class AlarmReceiverNotification extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        showNotification(context);
    }

    private void showNotification(Context context) {
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager
                = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.cancelAll();

        new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "1")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_pooper_notif)
                .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.notificationTitle))
                .setContentText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.notificationContent))
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setAutoCancel(true);
    }
}
```

---

**Permissions in AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
```

Expecting to happen is notification at exact set time repeating daily until overwritten.

Actual result notification at more than and hour and a half after scheduled time.

Parially working result using a setExact to accurately call the notification but does not repeat.

Target Api is latest (33) with minimum as 27

Comment: You should list out your existing manifest permissions as well as target API. See: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/changes/schedule-exact-alarms for info on future changes.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Thank you I have edited the post to show these.